# SwiftUI MatchedGeometryEffect not working when I move backward in position

Tags: swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

I have the matchedGeo working moving forward but for some reason, it doesn't work if I select a text moving backward. I have included a screenshot gif so you can see the issue.

```
import SwiftUI

enum CapsuleNavTitles: String, CaseIterable {
    case Discussion = "Discussion"
    case About = "About"
    case Memebers =  "Members"
}

struct CapsuleNavAnimationComponent: View {
    
    @State var currentNav: CapsuleNavTitles = .Discussion
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        CapsuleNav()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func CapsuleNav() -> some View {
        HStack() {
            ForEach(CapsuleNavTitles.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { nav in
                Text(nav.rawValue)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 9, leading: 17, bottom: 9, trailing: 17))
                    .background(currentNav == nav ? Capsule()
                        .fill(Color.buttonColor)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "CapsuleNavTitles", in: animation) : nil)
                    .foregroundColor(currentNav == nav ? .white : .black)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            currentNav = nav
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .background(Capsule().fill(Color.mainColor))
    }
}
```

[image: Gif of the issues of my matchedGeo]

Comment: I see this behavior in Preview, but not when running in the simulator.  I wouldn't worry too much about how Preview shows this.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more reliable way to use `matchedGeometryEffect`. I would suggest, the `Capsule` that you are applying in the background should be matched to one of the nav items. The item that has been selected is treated as the source, the `Capsule` itself is never the source.

The version below has the following changes:

- A `matchedGeometryEffeect` modifier has been added to each of the nav items, using the enum as id.
- The nav item matching the selection is identified as the source.
- The `Capsule` is now an overlay over the background.
- The `Capsule` adopts the current selection as its id for the `matchedGeometryEffect`.
- The `Capsule` always has `isSource = false`.

Here you go:

```swift
func CapsuleNav() -> some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(CapsuleNavTitles.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { nav in
            Text(nav.rawValue)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 9, leading: 17, bottom: 9, trailing: 17))
                .foregroundColor(currentNav == nav ? .white : .black)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: nav, in: animation, isSource: currentNav == nav)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        currentNav = nav
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    .background(
        Capsule().fill(Color.mainColor)
            .overlay {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color.buttonColor)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: currentNav, in: animation, isSource: false)
            }
    )
}
```